Permission error when executing New-GcsObject in PowerShell
I'm encountering an issue when running a line of code in PowerShell from a user with only read permissions. The line in question is as follows:
New-GcsObject -Bucket "$Bucket" -ObjectNamePrefix "ATTACHMENTS" -Folder $AttachmentsPath -Force #| Out-Null

When I execute this command from a PowerShell session as an administrator, it works perfectly. However, when I try to execute it from a user with limited permissions (read-only), I get the following error:
New-GcsObject : Access to the path 'D:\TEMP\BACKUPS\Attachments\emptyattachments.txt' is denied.
At line:49 char:1
+ New-GcsObject -Bucket "$Bucket" -ObjectNamePrefix "ATTACHMENTS" -Fold ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-GcsObject], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Google.PowerShell.CloudStorage.NewGcsObjectCmdlet

It's worth noting that the path 'D:\TEMP\BACKUPS\Attachments' exists and the user has read permissions on it.
Has anyone faced a similar issue before? Any help or suggestions on how to resolve this permissions issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
I tried everything.
I want to know what Windows permissions I need to give the user so they can run this. Since it should work with read only

Please be especifc with I tried everything. What's everything?

I want to know what Windows permissions I need to give the user so they can run this. Since it should work with read only
